# Sharepoint Changing URL Special characters

Tags: sharepoint, url-rewriting, codepages

I have a URL stored in a Sharepoint 'Link to a document' that contains the Nordic Character 'Ø' as hex(%D8). Sharepoint is encoding the % symbol, (thus making it %25D8).

If I enter the URL directly into an address bar, it works fine.
If I don't URL encode it, I still get the same problem.
Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the error - a 404?

Comment: Sounds like a serverfault.com question

Answer (score 0):

So what happens if the URL is stored as 'Ø' in the URL instead of already having it encoded?

Also do you have any special process running that stores it for you?  Because if you don't have any custom code interacting with this, this is probably better asked on serverfault.com.